# Compare 2 video files (could be in different formats and quality) by content

Tags: video

I'm interested - is it possible to implement algorithm which could compare 2 video files and answer, are they the same with some level of precision.
Is currently exist some methods which allow to solve that problem effectively?

The same - means like this. Let's assume we have a video file. All files created from this by different encoding (mpg, avi, m2v etc), quality change, removing some small parts (less then 5% for example) this is the same.

Comment: There is a whole research field concerned with image/video classification and pattern recognition, so your question seems to be too broad to answer in a couple of paragraphs. Please do some reading and come back with a more specific question. (Also, what do you mean by "the same"? Literally the same? File checksums. The same up to encoding? Can one be an extract from the other? The same news report with different overlays, say from different instances or new channels?)

Comment: I specify what is "same" means

Comment: The edited question still seems over-broad (it clarifies "the same", to some extent).